# How to separate php code from an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I apologize for the such a bad question title, but I couldn't come out with something better. I will try to explain my problem in a brief manner so that this community will face less difficulty in understanding my problem.

Currently I am working on a CMS project and I am responsible for developing templates for that CMS. All the components of a template are being loaded dynamically on the basis of whether they have been activated or not in the admin panel, and they are being dynamically loaded on frontend using PHP code which is echoing the HTML code.

The problem is much related to updating and maintaining the templates as the number of templates is getting increased.

When there is some change needed to be made in the php code, then if number of templates is 1 or 3 then updating the same php code in other templates is not that difficult, but if the number templates increases like up to 10 or more than it will become a difficulty and will be time consuming.

I am looking for a way by which I can separate the php code from the HTML. So that when a change is required to be made in the php then it should be implemented once and it affects all the templates, rather than updating each templates php code.

I hope I am able to explain my problem correctly, but if still some information is missing then please let me know.

Updated question with code sample for better explanation.

In the code sample I am loading html elements based on conditions. Now if I need to make change in this php code and I have five different template which use the same code then I need to update it five times in five different files.

I am looking a for way to separate this php code from html.

```html
echo'
      <div class="section my-common-section" id="section-'.$j.'>
        <div class="its_section_inner container-fluid my-4">
          <!-- Master Row -->
          <div class="row">
          <div id="product-specifications-container" class="container mt-5">';
          if(isset($a->heading) && !empty($a->heading)) {
            echo '
            <div class="row">
              <h3 class="subsec-title subsec-title-border text-center mt-3 mb-2">'.htmlspecialchars_decode($a->heading).'</h3>
            </div>';
          }
          echo'
          <div class="row">';
          $col1=$col2=false;
          if(!empty($a->video) || (!empty($a->image) && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/da/uploads/".$sub."/section/".$a->image))) {
            $col1 = true;
          }
          if(!empty($a->para)) {
            $col2 = true;
          }
          // if both video and paragraph options are available
          if($col1 && $col2) {
            if(!empty($a->video)) {
              echo '
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="col-content wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                  <iframe width="100%" style="min-height:'.$a->videoheight.'px;" src="'.$a->video.'?rel=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>';
            }
            else if(!empty($a->image) && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/da/uploads/".$sub."/section/".$a->image)) {
              echo '
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-xl-5">
                <div class="col-content wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                  <img class="" src="'. base_url() .'da/uploads/'. $sub .'/section/'. $a->image .'" alt="'. $a->title .'" title="'. $a->title .'">
                </div>
              </div>';
            }
            echo'
            <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-xl-7">
              <div class="col-content wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
              '. $this->customlib->cleanTable(nl2br(htmlspecialchars_decode($a->para))) .'
            </div>';
          }
          // if only video or image is available
          else if($col1){
            if(!empty($a->video)) {
              echo '
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-content wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                  <iframe width="100%" style="min-height:'.$a->videoheight.'px;" src="'.$a->video.'?rel=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                </div>
              </div>';
            }
            else if(!empty($a->image) && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/da/uploads/".$sub."/section/".$a->image)) {
              echo '
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-content wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
                  <img class="" src="'. base_url() .'da/uploads/'. $sub .'/section/'. $a->image .'" alt="'. $a->title .'" title="'. $a->title .'">
                </div>
              </div>';
            }
          }
          // if only paragraph is available
          else if($col2){
            echo'
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="col-content text-center wow animate__animated animate__fadeIn">';
                  echo'
                    '. $this->customlib->cleanTable(nl2br(htmlspecialchars_decode($a->para))) .'
              </div>
            </div>';
          }
          echo'
          </div>';
          if(isset($a->attachments) && !empty($a->attachments)) {
            echo'
            <div class="row mt-5">
              <div class="col-12 text-center">';
              foreach($a->attachments as $attachment) {
                echo'
                <a href="'.base_url().'da/uploads/'.$sub.'/attachments/'.$attachment->filename.'" download class="product-attachment my-2">
                  <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  '.$attachment->title.'
                </a>';
              }
              echo'
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- product attachment -->';
          }
          echo'
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Master Row -->';
          //Applying sub-sections
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such code? It's hard to see why you can't just use some classes and/or functions which you can then call from the templates - that's the standard way to make bits of common code re-usable in any application.

Comment: To me, this sounds like a simple case of [DRY vs WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), unless you can supply a simplified example to prove otherwise.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this even related to Angular, Vue, or Javascript? Why not use any of the multiple implementations of template systems?

Comment: I have added a sample code from a template which I have developed. This code is echoing html elements based on some conditions. Now if I want to update the php code and if there are five templates using the same code then I would need to update all five.

Comment: @NicoHaase I feel that Angular and Vue.js can give provide a solution to my problem by separating php logic from html.

Comment: Ok. That's why you separate this off into a function which returns the HTML, which you can then echo in your template. You can "include" the file containing the function code in every template where you need it. I assume you are aware of functions.

Comment: Angular and vue will not help you unless you completely redesign your approach so that you have an API in PHP which only outputs data, not HTML, and you have a single-page application structure rather than a traditional CMS. Anyway you shouldn't tag them unless your question relates to a problem with some code written in those frameworks.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, we can use functions but what if each template is displaying each component using different html code? For example the contact section of a each design has a unique layout and each layout has different html code, then how will be able to do it? Can we still use functions or should we go for something else?

Comment: `what if each template is displaying each component using different html code`...then they're different components. In your design, separating the PHP and HTML isn't necessary - the PHP in these views is just logic to ensure the correct HTML is output based on the data. It's fine for them to be together. What you should be aiming to do is create re-usable components so that you don't have to maintain the same (combination of PHP and HTML) code multiple times in order to get the same kind of output.

Comment: Or perhaps you just need a function which fetches different HTML snippets depending on which layout is selected. When you say "template" are you talking about a view template (e.g. a view template for displaying a list of products into which data is injected, or a view for showing previous orders), or a layout template like a theme (e.g. "dark theme" or "modern theme") which completely changes the appearance of every page on the site? It wasn't totally clear.

Comment: Yes. I am talking about a "template like a theme". It will completely change the layout of every page on the site.

Comment: If the layout is radically different then I'd expect the PHP would end up changing too in some cases? Or have you managed to avoid that? Why can't you use the same HTML for each theme, but just adjust the CSS to change the appearance? That's usually how themes work.

Comment: We have managed to avoid the change of php code. But some themes HTML requires to be different to give it a unique layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232037/discussion-between-lalit-pal-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Include Files**
if you feel yourself repeating, then you can create another file and store a piece of code there, wherever you need it, import that file using `include()`. for more details , i would like to take a look on this
http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/include-files/